# What is the resource id for column resize cursor?

Tags: mfc, clistctrl

I am trying to simulate the column resize cursor of clistctrl. But I don't know which resource id i need to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For MFC, from your application class use `CWinApp::LoadStandardCursor` ([MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0a4f8y8f.aspx)) with an argument of `IDC_SIZEWE` :

```
HCURSOR hCur = AfxGetApp()->LoadStandardCursor(IDC_SIZEWE);
```

Then when you want to display it, use the WinApi `SetCursor` function :

```
::SetCursor(hCur);
```

**UPDATE**

The actual cursor you refer to is defined in the Common Controls Library - COMCTL32.DLL - and can be viewed and/or exported as a `.cur` file from Visual Studio (just File/Open comctl32.dll from Windows/System32), or - as shown below - from any one of numerous free [resource hackers](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) :

[image: cursor]

Comment: But i need this cursor's resource id, refer the link

http://www.visionaustralia.org/images/assistive-technology/comp_adj_image016.gif?sfvrsn=0

Comment: Can you tell how to simulate this cursor?

Comment: @bala Well, you can just save it from the resource hacker (or export from Visual Studio) and then add that `*.cur` file as a cursor resource in your project and then use it as normal via `SetCursor` - is that what you mean?

Comment: You're right? But I am already using the comctrl in my project then why i need to save that file from comctrl.dll. No way to access that cursor directly by using that own resource ID ?

Comment: @bala Well, in theory, of course you can find the handle of that module and `LoadCursor` from it, but that will rely on the resource id staying the same over different releases of COMCTL32.DLL, which is not guaranteed. It's more robust to grab a copy of the resource and take control of it in your own project.

Answer (score 0):

IDC_SIZEWE

Use [LoadCursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms648391.aspx) with Hinstance NULL!